# Integer doesn't have the expected value in debugger

Tags: c++

Like any normal C++ programmer, when I type this code...

```
for (int m = 0; m < 3; m++){
    for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++){
        if (A[m].substr(size,location) == B[n].substr(size,location)){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the first value of m to be 0 in my iteration. (because I literally declared it as having a value of 0) However, my program was acting a tad funky, so I decided to look at it in the debugger. Interestingly, rather than having a starting value of 0, C++ decided that m should have a starting value of 32767.

Could someone explain to my why and how this could possibly happen?

Comment: Looks like some sort of integer over/underflow error. You could try printing out `m` from within the loop.

Comment: Depending on where the debugger was pausing, it might have paused at a spot where `m` was *declared* but not yet *initialized. Run one step in the debugger. Does it then get the value 0?

Comment: Are you compiling with optimization turned on/off?

Comment: the debugger showed the value before initialization, one of the calls in your loop is overwriting the stack, there are more explanations. You need to properly debug.

Comment: What debugger? Show us a screenshot.

Comment: Set the breakpoint on the second line ("for( int n = 0...") and you will see m == 0. @templatetypedef is surely right.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, templatetypedef was right. Once I stepped over to the next breakpoint its value was initialized. Thanks guys!